# Clicking on the second of the two identical elements in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am writing the test automaton code for a system and the dev team presented me the following html:

```
<div id="someId">
  <div class="classA">
    <button class="classB">
  </div>
  <div class="classA">
    <button class="classB">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the question is: Is it possible to click exclusively on the SECOND button? If so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not rely on the order of elements returned by `all`. I remember running into issues with it in the past, see e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/713). Instead I'd use a selector, something like this:

```
find("#someId div.classA:nth-child(1) button.classB").click
```

(IIRC they are zero-indexed)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you're click on links styled as buttons.  You can use this step definition

```
Then(/^I click the (\d+) instance of link "(.*?)"$/) do |instance, link|
   page.all('a', :text => "#{link}")[instance.to_i - 1].click    
end
```

Comment: Actually - no. These are not links, these are buttons created with tag: <button class='blabla' type="button", aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 123px;">. Both are identical.